# Script to perform remote login and execute another local script

Tags: linux, scripting, remote-access, expect

I have to write a script which performs remote login and authentication and execute a local script on remote.

My original code is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh user@ip "bash -ls" < ./script.bash
expect "password"
send "abc123/r"
interact
```

which gives following on running by ./my_script.sh

```
spawn ssh user@ip "bash -ls" < ./script.bash
user@ip's password:
./script.bash: No such file or directory
```

However, if I run the script without argument i.e. just

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh user@ip
expect "password"
send "abc123/r"
interact
```

It gets successfully login.

Also if I run directly through terminal without script like

```
ssh user@ip "bash -ls" < ./script.bash
```

then local file is getting executed successfully at remote server after taking password through prompt. Hence can you please suggest how to make my original code to work successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because expect does not understand the shell's input redirection. Try this:

```
spawn sh -c {ssh user@ip "bash -ls" < ./script.bash}
```

If "user" or "ip" is a variable, we'll need different quoting. Such as

```
spawn sh -c "ssh $user@$ip 'bash -ls'  < ./script.bash"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Can you explain a bit how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path to `script.bash`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh user@ip "bash -ls" < /the/full/path/script.bash
expect "password"
send "abc123/r"
interact
```

Comment: Initially I was working with full path only. No benefit. It is giving same error.

Comment: I am not very proficient in shell scripting hence please bear with me. But given answer is only performing remote login using shell script, which I have also successfully done.I am facing problem in executing a local script on remote machine in that script